# Prevent form from submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this:

```
$("#contact-frm-2").bind("jqv.form.result", function(event , errorFound){
    if(!errorFound){
        alert('go!');
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;                               
    }
});
```

It supposed to validate the form for errors and when there is no error on the form, alert "Go!" without submitting.
I am using the jquery.ValidationEngine.js you can find at http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

I am sure

```
event.preventDefault();
            return false;
```

is supposed to prevent the form from submitting but it is still submitting. Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: just remove if error found blabla and put it to your form's submit event `$('#form_id').submit(...);`

Comment: Well the idea to run another function when there is no error on the form. The other function I need to call after form validation will still run even if there errors on the form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ["onsubmit" JavaScript event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/form.submit) will handle this for you.

jQuery:

```
$('#formid').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Pure JS:

```
document.getElementById('formid').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This is supposed to work. but for some reasons, maybe due to the plugin, it is not work. Pffff!.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#form_id').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `return false;` should prevent your form from being submitted, but only if you execute it on the actual `submit` event. Your code above looks like it is dependent on the plugin. Why don't you try attaching an additional listener to the actual submit button in your form.

```
$("#submit_btn").on('click',function(){
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin has options that can be used. One of them is OnvalidationComplete which does the trick as shown below:

```
jQuery("#contact-frm-2").validationEngine('attach', {
   promptPosition : "centerRight", scroll: true,
   onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
   alert("The form status is: " +status+", it will never submit");
   }  
});
```

Full documentation is here http://posabsolute.github.com/jQuery-Validation-Engine/