# Stop form from submitting

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I created a signup form using Bootstrap's signin form example code, and I'm trying to perform a crude verification on the form before the form action takes place. However, I'm noticing that even though I `return false` the form action still get's submitted and I get loaded to the form action page. How can I stop this from happening *when the values of the form are invalid* (ie: email is something like `abcdef`).

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CCsJn/1/

Notice that even though the code returns false, the form submits.

Searching brought me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461755/prevent-form-from-submitting), but that code did not work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly me! It was a typo!

```
if ((email.value.length == 0) || (!validateEmail(email))){
        alert("Valid email is required.");
        elem.focus();
        return false;
}
```

`elem.focus()` should be `email.focus()`

Comment: I was just coming back to say, when I remove that line, it works fine. Don't feel bad. Most of the time I ask someone something, I figure it out myself before finishing the sentence.

Comment: You can mark your answer as... Well, the answer. :P

Comment: For future reference, when you are testing something like this, wrap your code in a try/catch and always return false to begin with so that you can eliminate unknowns in the process. In this instance your js was throwing an error so the form was submitting regardless of whether validation was passed.  

Here's what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/CCsJn/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this at the end for the condition

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
             return false;
```

but for this you will have to define an event 1st, which will be your condition. 
If the exact thing doesnt help, read thru stopImmediatePropagation and preventDefault. I had the same problem, and this helped me